# Definite integral question with negative variable in integral

Tags: calculus, integration

How would I solve the following question.

$$F(X)=\int\limits_x^2\frac{t-1}{t^2+1}dt$$

Find $\;F'(0)\;,\;\,F''(0)$

For my first question I got $F'(0)$

$$F'(0)=-\frac{0-1}{0^2+1}=-(-1)=1$$

$$F''(x)=\frac{-x^2+2x+1}{(x^2+1)^2}$$

$$F''(0)=-1$$

But would this be correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, indeed. Your work is correct, until you compute $F''(0)$

Check again, and you should find that $F''(0) = 1$.

$$F''(x)=\dfrac{-x^2+2x+1}{(x^2+1)^2} \implies F''(0) = \dfrac{-0 + 0 + 1}{(0 + 1)^2} = \frac{1}{1} = 1$$

Comment: Would It be $F''(0)=-1$

Comment: No, $F''(x) = 1$. Notice the only negation in $F''(x)$ is the term $-x^2$ in the numerator. But evaluated at $x = 0$, it has no impact because $-(0^2) = - 0 = 0.$ Your evaluation would be correct only if the numerator of $F''(x) = -(x^2 + 2x + 1)$, but that is not what the numerator is. The scope of the negative sign in $F''(x)$ applies only to the term $x^2$ in the numerator.

Comment: yes that makes sense thanks.

Comment: @amWhy: Nice interaction and follow - up +1